# Send bitmap from c# to external api parameter which is UCHAR

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am using DLLImport to interface my c# application to an external api .dll which is native c++.

The api function requires UCHAR as a parameter where a bitmap is passed to it.
I am converting my bitmap to a byte array.
Then, passing to the api function.
The api is receiving the image successfully and give me a success code.
But it is changing the bit depth from 1 to 8 and needs to be 1.
And, this is apparent when viewing the actual file before compared to the file that the api generates from my bytes passed to it.

HERE IS MY METHOD DECLARATION:

```
[DllImport("XIJET_API.dll")]
    private static extern bool XIJET_CanvasWrite([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] IntPtr PrinterHandle,
        UInt32 VerticalOffset,
        UInt32 HorizontalOffset,
        UInt32 VerticalHeight,
        UInt32 HorizontalWidth,
        Byte[] pBitmappedBuffer);
```

HERE IS MY USAGE OF THE METHOD:

```
    Bitmap bmp2load = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(strFilePath);
            UInt32 bmpH = (UInt32)bmp2load.Height;
            UInt32 bmpW = (UInt32)bmp2load.Width;
            Byte[] bmpbytes = Functions.PublicFunctions.Image2ByteArray(bmp2load);
            bmp2load.Dispose();

XIJET_CanvasWrite(printer, (UInt32)0, (UInt32)0, bmpW, bmpH, bmpbytes);
```

HERE ARE THE HEADER BYTES FROM MY BITMAP JUST BEFORE I PASS THE BYTES TO THE API FUNCTION:
Everything looks correct in the header according to 1bpp format.

```
-       bmpbytes    {byte[25993262]}    byte[]
        [0] 66  byte
        [1] 77  byte
        [2] 46  byte
        [3] 160 byte
        [4] 140 byte
        [5] 1   byte
        [6] 0   byte
        [7] 0   byte
        [8] 0   byte
        [9] 0   byte
        [10]    62  byte
        [11]    0   byte
        [12]    0   byte
        [13]    0   byte
        [14]    40  byte
        [15]    0   byte
        [16]    0   byte
        [17]    0   byte
        [18]    96  byte
        [19]    9   byte
        [20]    0   byte
        [21]    0   byte
        [22]    116 byte
        [23]    82  byte
        [24]    1   byte
        [25]    0   byte
        [26]    1   byte
        [27]    0   byte
        [28]    1   byte
        [29]    0   byte
        [30]    0   byte
        [31]    0   byte
        [32]    0   byte
        [33]    0   byte
        [34]    0   byte
        [35]    0   byte
        [36]    0   byte
        [37]    0   byte
        [38]    70  byte
        [39]    92  byte
        [40]    0   byte
        [41]    0   byte
        [42]    70  byte
        [43]    92  byte
        [44]    0   byte
        [45]    0   byte
        [46]    2   byte
        [47]    0   byte
        [48]    0   byte
        [49]    0   byte
        [50]    2   byte
        [51]    0   byte
        [52]    0   byte
        [53]    0   byte
        [54]    0   byte
```

HERE ARE THE INSTRUCTIONS FROM THEIR DOCUMENTATION:
[image]

HERE ARE THE IMAGE FILES BEFORE AND AFTER.
[2 Bitmap files before and after](https://wcframing.sharepoint.com/iN4/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=1ad9c3c6e184b446ca9fcbaf5c1bfd0f4&authkey=AYDrE3VCBSI2bWx4NdLjCGw)

Comment: What do you mean by bit depth?  If the format was incorrect you would not see the image.  So the byte array is correct.

Comment: i think he means with bit depth the image-quality, or something sent in the header for compression purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, the bit depth is the color depth.  For this application it requires a monochrome bitmap of 1bit per pixel.  I just got an update from the manufacturer about their api and they confirmed that is does create it as 8 bit depth so that is not the problem, now.  The real problem at this point is that the image is being created like it is a photo-negative, meaning black and white are being reversed by the interpreting api because of something in my bitmap header.  That is the 54bytes in my post.  Perhaps, you guys see the problem there, I do not, yet.